# Which license should I use for my own extension to prevent others to use it without my permission/paying?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, license

I developed a few extensions and I try to figure out which license I should use to "prevent" others e.g. our agencies to copy them and spread them to their own customers w/o my permission.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5309/146

Comment: @Marius, In your link the person who asks the question says that his module is free, but mine should not be free, so what license should I use?!

Comment: That's why I didn't add it as a solution, but I added as a comment. maybe it helps, maybe it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/), you don't need a license in my case.

> "If you find software that doesn’t have a license, that generally
>   means you have no permission from the creators of the software to use,
>   modify, or share the software."

### Edit: Hold on... if you don't have permission to use the software, then it makes no sense. So I still need some license... so ignore this answer please.